# Date Picker attached to InputText tag

Tags: java, jsf

In JSF, I would like to have a date helper attached to an h:inputText tag. The input text could either be a string or a date. I would just like something that would help the user input a correct date if thats what they are choosing.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try [jQuery DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger), if you are using just JSF and don't want rich, prime or anything else.

Usage:

Page

```
<h:inputText id="InpDate" />
```

Javascript

```
$("#InpDate").datepicker({
   showOn: "button",
   buttonImage: "../images/calendarIcon.png",
   buttonImageOnly: true
}).mask("99/99/9999");
```

This will "attach" a calendar icon in your input, as you want. Maybe you will need to use "formId:InpDate" to get it working, but im not sure about this..

Comment: this will not work with Id. The rendered HTML will have a changed id(form id appended). Style class can be used to avoid this problem.